# How to color lines in a listbox?

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox

Hy! 
I would like display my log system output on a listbox, with custom highlighting depending on the level or log entry. (General, warning, error, debug, trace)

```
somelistbox.Items.Add("Starting"); // I would like to drawn this as grey
somelistbox.Items.Add("Error!"); // I would like to drawn this as red
```

So I would like to add a new thing, like typeoflog, but I dont know how to do it.

```
somelistbox.Items.Add("Error!",Type.Error);
```

I've got this code, which colors items , depends on item number, but Thats not what I'm looking for.

```
    private void general_log_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Brush myBrush = Brushes.Black;
        switch (actualLogType)
        {
            case LogTypes.General:
                myBrush = Brushes.Black;
                break;
            case LogTypes.Warning:
                myBrush = Brushes.Orange;
                break;
            case LogTypes.Error:
                myBrush = Brushes.Purple;
                break;
            case LogTypes.Debug:
                myBrush = Brushes.AntiqueWhite;
                break;
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(((ListBox)sender).Items[e.Index].ToString(),
            e.Font, myBrush, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```

**UPDATE : If anyone still looking into this, I'ld suggest to take a look at the NLog project. It has colored richtextbox target.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ListBox can store more than just strings, it can also store objects.  You want to take advantage of that here, the list item in your case has more state than just the text.  Add a little nested helper class:

```
    private enum itemType { error, warning }

    private class listObject {
        public listObject(string txt, itemType type) { Text = txt; Type = type; }
        public string Text;
        public itemType Type;
        public override string ToString() { return Text; }
    }
```

Note how the ToString() override generates the text that the user sees.  Now just add items to the listbox like this:

```
        listBox1.Items.Add(new listObject("blah", itemType.warning));
```

And cast the object back to your class in the DrawItem event handler:

```
    private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
        var obj = listBox1.Items[e.Index] as listObject;
        // etc..
    }
```

And use obj.Type to determine colors.

Comment: Your code is freaking cool, but I cant get it to work yet. Could you write me the whole DrawnItem method please? Thank you very very much!

here is how I try it http://pastie.org/1175240

Comment: You do actually have to use a different brush if you want a different color.  Use switch(obj.Type) {} to create it.  Just like you did it in your original code snippet.

Comment: You need to check e.Index and only do the custom drawing code if the value >= 0.  Add an if() statement.

Comment: Hmm, I debugged it now, and the problem is, that the DrawnItem event is not called when I click my button :/

        private void bot_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            general_log_add_item("ASDASD", Logging.LogTypes.General);
        }

Comment: Well, the item is not visible perhaps.  Scroll the list box.  Please start a new question, this is getting pretty far removed from the original one.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not WPF listbox, you need to use Win32 API. Is that what you are after?

**UPDATE**

Using WIn32 API is not necessary:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ColorListBoxIcons.aspx

Comment: Its not WPF listbox. How to do that?

Comment: Well, there is a managed way as well, look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ColorListBoxIcons.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a ListView instead of ListBox, so you could access its BackColor property:

```
listView1.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
```